# Finding Multiple Files at Once

Tags: finder, macos, spotlight, mp3

I am learning French and I have a folder with 5000 words in it (ie 5000 mp3 files).

Out of the 5000 words there are 1243 that I still don't know. I want to extract those 1243 words and put them into a separate folder.

I have the 1243 file names listed in Excel, eg "autrement.mp3"

How do I search for them all at once, or in batches?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/1qk525/how_do_you_search_for_multiple_items_all_at_once/

This worked for me:

Use the free software called EasyFind

- Drag and drop your root folder in the window to set the source
- Copy paste the list of photos you're looking for (you'll only see one in the box but they're all there if you arrow up/down.
- Select "Any Word" in the options on the left
- Hit enter to search
- Select all the items in that list and copy (option+drag) or move them (drag) to a folder in finder.

Comment: copy and paste the list where?

Comment: This is a very old 32 bit app, MacOS cannot run it, it puts a X over the app icon. The full Answer text above is a perfect copy/part from a 5 years old reply from reddit. I don't think this answer help others with similar problems. But for Sierra or older MacOS versions, it may work. Answer needs clarifications,

Comment: @Prado The EasyFind option is still relevant. I downloaded the latest version 5.0.2 from https://easyfind.en.softonic.com/mac and it worked perfectly in finding multiple files from an Excel sheet.